# Help in interpreting "no commercial use" of the copyright

Tags: copyright

I have two questions concerning copyright.

I need sometimes, to go to a website and listen to some sound samples to make a decision. If I then specify in a document the items in a contract, based on what i am listening to those samples, am I infringing?

On one of the pages it says that it is prohibited to use the website for "any for profit uses".

http://www.organstops.org/_apps/Copyright.html

How is non-commercial use usually decided on, and how can someone test to make sure what they are doing will avoid copyright infringement?

Comment: I made some edits to correct some spelling and grammar mistakes that made your post harder to read.  Please take a look and check that I haven't accidentally changed the meaning, and feel free to make further edits if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using things you have heard or read on a web site to make a decision and list items in a contract, without making a copy of content from the site, is not an infringement if copyright. Copyright never protects ideas, only ways of expressing ideas, such as specific words, images, and musical sounds.

"commercial use" as a restriction in a copyright license, is usually interpreted to mean any use where the re-user is charging a fee. Sometimes charging a nominal fee, only enough to reclaim expenses, is not considered "commercial". The term "non-profit"  in such a license probably means that ther is no purpose of gain, even if a fee is charged.

The license on the linked page, which reads:

> Permission is granted to use small excerpts from this work for educational and/or non-profit purposes, as long as due credit is given to the author.
>
> Copying in whole, or in large excerpts, via any medium, is expressly forbidden without written permission from the author, with the exception of quoted material in the public domain, or quoted material covered by another copyright.
>
> Any for-profit use is likewise forbidden without written permission from the author.

In probably not enforceable as written under US law. Limited use of copyrighted content, even in a for-profit enterprise, may well constitute *fair use*, and no license may prohibit a person from exercising fair-use rights.  In some cases reuse of a whole work may be fair use.

Some such re-use which this license seeks to forbid might be "fair dealing" unde the laws of those countries which use that concept.

Comment: _Directive (EU) 2019/790 on copyright and related rights in the Digital Single Market_ has similar objections against this license. Moral rights (credit to the author) are a matter of national law, text mining is allowed without license. Museums may make verbatim copies for preservation. Collective licensing may apply.

Comment: Legal language in contracts tends to be pretty boiler-plate in my experience. Try doing a search for the phrases you want to use and see how many come up. If many do, then it's probably safe to use (note: I am not a lawyer and do not represent this as legal advice!); if more than 1 does, maybe; if one 1 and that's your source then rephrase it.